# Why I can't add elements on AsyncTask in this style

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm new to Android and encountered this problems in Android. Basically I want have a list view and implemented a customised list adapter for it. For that adapter, I need to initialise it with a list, which contain data fetched from certain website. I decide to do it using AsyncTask.

My original code is as following:

```
public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..........Other codes.........

    initData();
    mAdapter = new MainContentListAdapter(mList);

    ....................
}

public class FetchQTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MainContentListItem>> {

    ...... Some other codes ......

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MainContentListItem> results) {
        if(mList!=null) mList.clear();
        else mList = new ArrayList<MainContentListItem>();
        for(MainContentListItem result : results) {
            mList.add(result);
        }
        progressDialog.cancel();
    }
}

 private void initData(){
    FetchQTask qTask = new FetchQTask();
    qTask.execute();
}
```

But there is no data in the mList when the App launch. Specifically, when I try to use debug mode, the program clearly run into the "add element" part but for some reason clear it. I doubt whether the logic of my code is incorrect but cannot find the reason. After some blindly try, I decide to move the "new ArrayList part outside of AsyncTask", as you see, currently my code looks like:

```
public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..........Other codes.........

    mList = new ArrayList<>();
    initData();
    mAdapter = new MainContentListAdapter(mList);

    ....................
}

public class FetchQTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MainContentListItem>> {

    ...... Some other codes ......

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MainContentListItem> results) {
        if (results != null) {
            mList.clear();
            for(MainContentListItem result : results) {
                mList.add(result);
            }
        }
        progressDialog.cancel();
    }
}

 private void initData(){
    FetchQTask qTask = new FetchQTask();
    qTask.execute();
}
```

And now it works! The question I want to ask is why is that case? I don't even know what happened. Is it related to allocate memory in another thread?

Sorry for my foolish, but really appreciate for any help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have to maintain the same instance of your "mList" Array after instanciate your adapter with this Array.
In the first case, you clear the mList and re-instanciate it in your onPostExecute method, so the instance of the Array you set in your adapter is not the same than the new instance :

```
public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..........Other codes.........

    --> mList = new ArrayList<MainContentListItem>();
    initData();
    mAdapter = new MainContentListAdapter(mList);

    ....................
}

public class FetchQTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MainContentListItem>> {

    ...... Some other codes ......

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MainContentListItem> results) {
        // Here your mList array is not null because already instanciate onCreateView method.
        for(MainContentListItem result : results) {
            mList.add(result);
        }
        progressDialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! That's it. I have thought about whether the list is different but I didn't come up with this idea. Really thank you for your help.